# Cant get through the setDescription() function there is always an missing ) after args TypeError

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi So I was making an embed in whose description I tried to add a code block with js markdown discord supports and I am encountering the following error! Please assist me [here is the code to it](https://hastebin.com/lihaleredi.typescript)

````sh
.setDescription("This is how to do it! ```js\n const fetch = require("node-fetch");\n const express = require("express");\n const app = express();\n let status = 404;\n app.get("/", (req, res) => {\n res.status(status).send("HEY!");\n console.log("Ping!");\n });\n const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;\n app.listen(port);\n console.log(port);\n setInterval(async () => {\n const response = await fetch("LIVE APP HERE");\n console.log(`Status - ${response.status}`);\n status = response.status;\n }, 30e4);```\n **Just add this particular code to your main file that are serverjs indexjs botjs etc and replace the text in line 13 with your live app!")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:127:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `"` in your description for the requires and string output in general. You need to either escape those with a backspace `\"` or choose other string definitions, such as either single ticks `'` or template strings: (`).

I suggest you to use the single ticks `'` because you are not templating within there.

So `setDescription` should look like this:

````js
.setDescription("This is how to do it! ```js\n const fetch = require('node-fetch');\n const express = require('express');\n const app = express();\n let status = 404;\n app.get('/', (req, res) => {\n res.status(status).send('HEY!');\n console.log('Ping!');\n });\n const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;\n app.listen(port);\n console.log(port);\n setInterval(async () => {\n const response = await fetch('LIVE APP HERE');\n console.log(`Status - ${response.status}`);\n status = response.status;\n }, 30e4);```\n **Just add this particular code to your main file that are serverjs indexjs botjs etc and replace the text in line 13 with your live app!")
````